# 'sklearn.linear_model' has no attribute 'PoissonRegressor'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn import linear_model
p_model = linear_model.PoissonRegressor()
```

After this I'm getting an bellow error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-151-56a5434ffcb5> in <module>
----> 1 p_model = linear_model.PoissonRegressor()

AttributeError: module 'sklearn.linear_model' has no attribute 'PoissonRegressor'
```

I am not sure how to fix this error.

Comment: I fixed the problem by "pip install --upgrade scikit-learn".

Comment: Irrespectively if you found the answer on your own or after the answer below was posted, please *accept* the answer, so that the question is marked as resolved and thus helpful for others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.PoissonRegressor.html), `PoissonRegressor()` is a relatively new addition to sklearn (version 0.23).

Probably your version is not up to date, so try upgrading the whole library:

```
pip install --upgrade scikit-learn
```

or

```
conda update scikit-learn
# you can also try `conda install scikit-learn=0.24`
```

depending on which package manager you are using.